# Can a Muslim man marry a non-Muslim woman who only believes there is one God?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim

Can a Muslim man marry a non-Muslim woman who only believes there is one supreme power (God) and doesn't follow any other teachings and agreed to let future children to follow Islam?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

No. The general rule is that marrying disbelievers is forbidden.

> وَلَا تُمْسِكُوا بِعِصَمِ ا**لْكَوَافِرِ**
>
> And hold not to marriage bonds with **disbelieving women**.
>
> <sub>[Quran 60:10](https://quran.com/60/10)</sub>

With an exception specifically for those "*given the book before you*".

> الْيَوْمَ أُحِلَّ لَكُمُ الطَّيِّبَاتُ ۖ وَطَعَامُ الَّذِينَ أُوتُوا
>   الْكِتَابَ حِلٌّ لَّكُمْ وَطَعَامُكُمْ حِلٌّ لَّهُمْ ۖ
>   وَالْمُحْصَنَاتُ مِنَ الْمُؤْمِنَاتِ وَالْمُحْصَنَاتُ **مِنَ الَّذِينَ
>   أُوتُوا الْكِتَابَ مِن قَبْلِكُمْ**
>
> This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those
>   who were given the Scripture is lawful for you and your food is lawful
>   for them. And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the
>   believers and chaste women from **among those who were given the
>   Scripture before you.**
>
> <sub>[Quran 5:5](https://quran.com/5/5)</sub>

So, following the literal meaning, monotheists who don't follow a divine book are not included.